# Does Java have an equivalent to C#'s Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()?

Tags: java, command-line-arguments

I know that I can get the command-line arguments in the "main" method, but I need to be able to get them **indirectly**.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You may want to rethink your design if you have to do something like this.

Comment: I think that the answer is that you can't.

Comment: @Mike The class that needs the arguments needs to have access to the true command-line arguments, even if objects which instantiate it do not themselves have access to them. Since my class is part of a library, there is no way to ensure that classes that use the library will have access to the command-line arguments, even though they will need to use my class. In addition, this problem is not significant enough to the overall design to force other classes to change their design.

Comment: This is just counter to Java design philosophy. If you have a class that needs information from 'the outside world', call System.getProperty and thus examine the -D's from the arg list. You class might be run via the invocation interface from an environment where there is *no such thing as command line args.*

Comment: It just makes no sense to me. I may use "-f" in the command line meaning "force" or "file" or whatever, what does it buy to *you* knowing there's "-f" on *my* command line? You can't make any sense of it.

Answer (score 9):

Following expression is exactly what you want:

System.getProperty("sun.java.command")

Comment: This works only sometimes, as this is not a property that is guaranteed to be present. I'd not rely on this alone. Generally, from a design perspective, storing the values somewhere is better.

Answer (score 2):

You can list the threads, find the main thread, and crawl down the stack trace until you find the call to main, and pull out the args.

*update* a comment points out that this won't work all by itself, and I think the comment is correct. I misremembered the capabilities of stack introspection or mentally mixed in JVMTI.

So, here's plan B. Connect to yourself with JMX. The VM Summary MBean has the args.

```
Connection name: 
pid: 77090 com.basistech.jdd.JDDLauncher -config src/main/config/benson-laptop-config.xml
```

All this having been said, what you *should* do is call `System.getProperty` and live with the need to use -D to pass parameters from the outside world down into your cave.

Comment: How would you pull out the arguments?  They are not in a `StackTraceElement` object.

Answer (score -1):

You could write a wrapper to take the cli and re-format it to use -DPROP=VAL

```
int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
std::vector<std::string> in (argv+1,argv+argc), out();

out.push_back("java.exe");
out.push_back("-cp");
out.push_back("my-jar.jar");
out.push_back("main.class")

for( auto it = in.begin(); it!=in.end(); ++in)
{
//process CLI args. turn "-abc","BLAH" into "-Darg.a=true","-Darg.b=true","-Darg.c=BLAH" and push to out
//Do additional processing. Maybe evn use get_opt() or Boost.ProgramOptions
}
//use exec or CreateProcess to launch java with the proper args
//or even use something like WinRun4J's methods to load the jvm.dll
//Then your program shows up as "MyExe.exe" instead of "java.exe"

//Use System.getProperty("arg.a","false") to get the value of a
}
```

Of course, you could always just tell you users to invoke a bash/batch script with the proper -DA=true type arguments