# Java: How to determine startup arguments without the main line access?

Tags: java, command-line-arguments

I'm curious to know if it is possible to determine the startup arguments of a Java application when you don't have access to the arguments array from the main line.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // Invokes my code without providing arguments.
    mycode();
}

public static void mycode()
{
    // Attempting to determine arguments here.
    // TODO GetArgs()
}
```

I'm in this situation by doing some plugin work and the core application does not provide a list of startup arguments. Any thoughts?

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Does Java have an equivalent to C#'s Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765745/does-java-have-an-equivalent-to-cs-environment-getcommandlineargs). And I'm sorry to say the answer appears to basically be "no."

Comment: Yea, seems like a duplicate (couldn't find it for some reason).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not unless the plugin is given them, but that kind of goes without saying (at least in Java).

If you need to set some options specifically for your plugin, but can't access the command line, there are at least two options:

- Options file (several mechanisms)
- Set system params on the command line

For the second option, just use the normal `-D` option and namespace the param name, like:

```
java -Dcom.davelnewton.plugins.foo.bar=anOptionValue etc...
```

Retrieve them via [`System.getProperty(anOptionName)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty%28java.lang.String%29) or one of its cousins.

IMO an options file is a better (ahem) option, even if you're specifying the file path on the command line, but if you only have an option or two, maybe not--just depends.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the arguments to the function?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    mycode(args);
}

public static void mycode(String[] args)
{
    String arg1 = args[0];
}
```

Comment: He said: *"I'm in this situation by doing some plugin work and the core application does not provide a list of startup arguments."*

Comment: If the application does not provide the start arguments then he wont be able to get the start arguments. That would be a non-question without knowing more information.

Comment: @ Jivings: No, the question is: Is it possible, in Java, to get access to those arguments in some other way? (It is in many other environments.) But this answer just completely ignores a key aspect of the question and so is not useful.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Oh right, I see. I didn't get that from the question. My apologies.

Comment: @ Jivings: There's that tempting "delete" link under the answer... ;-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I like to have a constant reminder of my mistakes :P

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  
{  
    System.setProperty("cmdArgs", args);
    mycode();  
}  

public static void mycode()  
{  
    // Attempting to determine arguments here.  
    String[] args = System.getProperty("cmdArgs");

}
```